# Any method to get constant for HTTP GET, POST, PUT, DELETE?

Tags: java, servlets, constants, http-method

For example, `HttpServletResponse` has the HTTP status codes as constants like

```
public static final int SC_OK = 200;
public static final int SC_CREATED = 201;
public static final int SC_BAD_REQUEST = 400;
public static final int SC_UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
public static final int SC_NOT_FOUND = 404;
```

Is there any such constants defined for HTTP methods like `GET`, `POST`, ..., anywhere in the Java EE API so that it could be referenced easily, rather than creating one on my own?

Comment: `HttpServlet` class declares them but they are `private`. Write your own, possibly as enums instead.

Comment: Please, https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE (apart from incorrectly using a tag in the title instead of keeping it in the tags)

Comment: @BalusC this post tells that is not possible, which was true until Java 5. I took Matt's answer and his link to the full list of constants. I found that those constants actually exist since Java 6.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are using Spring, you have this enum `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod`

```
public enum RequestMethod {
  GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE;
}
```

**EDIT** : Here is the [complete list of constants values in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html) You can see that some of those are available in the class [HttpMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/HttpMethod.html) but it contains less values than RequestMethod.

```
public @interface HttpMethod {
  java.lang.String GET = "GET";
  java.lang.String POST = "POST";
  java.lang.String PUT = "PUT";
  java.lang.String DELETE = "DELETE";
  java.lang.String HEAD = "HEAD";
  java.lang.String OPTIONS = "OPTIONS";

  java.lang.String value();
}
```

Comment: That annotation is in the Java EE API stack, but not available in a `servlet-api`, which I assume is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: I like complete list of constants